# Angular Reactive Form: Nested Radio Buttons and Checkboxes

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I try to create a reactive form of this kind:

```
(o) Some radio button
( ) Another radio button
    [ ] A nested checkbox, disabled as long "Another radio button" is not selected
    [ ] Another checkbox, disabled as long "Another radio button" is not selected
```

The checkboxes are disabled in the state shown above. If the second radio button is activated, the checkboxes can also be selected.

How do I model that in Angular.io with reactive forms? One could view it as a single control, with values:

- artificial value representing selection of first radio button
- value of first checkbox
- value of second checkbox

Another way would be that it is a boolean FormControl, but in case of one value another FormControl is added below, but I don't think this is possible.

What is the best way to model that in reactive forms logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your checkbox options are fixed then you could create a nested `FormGroup`  for the "Another radio button" options in the ngOnInit:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({

      radioGroup: '0',
      ckBoxGroup2: this.fb.group({
        ckBoxG2_1: { value: false, disabled: true },
        ckBoxG2_2: { value: false, disabled: true },
      })
    });
```

Then in the same ngOnInit method subscribe to valueChange Observable of the radio button control. Of course, the are other ways to react to changes but I like this:

```
    this.form.get('radioGroup').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      value === '2' ? this.form.get('ckBoxGroup2.ckBoxG2_1').enable() : this.form.get('ckBoxGroup2.ckBoxG2_1').disable();
      value === '2' ? this.form.get('ckBoxGroup2.ckBoxG2_2').enable() : this.form.get('ckBoxGroup2.ckBoxG2_2').disable();
    });
```

In the template create the same structure:

```
<form [formGroup]=form>

  <input type="radio" value="1" formControlName="radioGroup">Group 1<br />

  <input type="radio" value="2" formControlName="radioGroup">Group 2
  <div formGroupName="ckBoxGroup2" style="margin-left: 20px" >
    <div>
      <label>CheckBox 1
        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="ckBoxG2_1">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>CheckBox 2
        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="ckBoxG2_2">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Check this demo I made based on your example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfcznq

Comment: Thank you very much, now I start to understand. I was too much focused on how the controls are shown to the user and I tried to mimic that in the way I design the FormControl structures :-)